# Tool for data series analysis

Tags: math-software

I am looking for a tool for time series analysis. What do I need is comparing two arrays with data and get some information how do they correlate. Examples:

```
arrayA = [1,2,3,4,5]
arrayB = [3,6,9,12,15]
```

I expect from program output like: `arrayB = arrayA * 3`

Another example:

```
arrayA = [1,2,3,4,5]
arrayB = [4,7,10,13,16]
```

I expect from program something like: `arrayB = (arrayA * 3) + 1`

Is there any application on the market that could help with that?

Comment: This has nothing to do with time series.  Just linear interpolation (or linear regression if there is noise).

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks for comment. I wrote "time series" because I would like to compare data from music (wav files), so these data points are indexed in time order. Example `[1,2,3,4,5]` 1 refers to 1/44100 second

Comment: This is not what the tag `time-series` is about.

Comment: @user10354138 Ok, now I understand, I edited my question

Comment: Time series methods might be appropriate to analysing a piece of music. Where there are repeated sections, autocorrelation would be a useful thing to use.

Comment: @tomi Thanks for your comment!